# Enable Macro button on protected sheet - Excel

Tags: excel, vba, validation, protected

I have a `macro` that copies `rows` from one `sheet` to another. However, I want to protect this `sheet` from editing. When I do this though, I cant get the `macro` to run. I've played around with the different locked properties and it still doesn't work.

This is what Ive attempted:

```
Option Explicit

Dim pwd As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
pwd = "password"

ws.Unprotect password:=pwd
Next ws

Sub FilterAndCopy()
    Dim rng As Range, sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht1 = Worksheets("SHIFT LOG")
    Set sht2 = Worksheets("CHANGE OF NO'S")

    sht2.UsedRange.ClearContents

    With Intersect(sht1.Columns("B:BP"), sht1.UsedRange)
        .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        If .Parent.AutoFilterMode Then .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Change of Numbers"

        .Range("A:F, AD:AD, BL:BO").Copy Destination:=sht2.Cells(4, "B")
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

        .Range("F:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        .Range("AE:BK").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
   End With

    'Go to last cell in column B
    With ActiveSheet
    Range("B5").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    End With

End Sub

ws.Protect password:=pwd
Next ws
```

Comment: Yes you can use the protect and unprotect sheet or you can block the cells that you want to protect...

Comment: I've tried putting the code in between that protect function but it doesnt work

Comment: I think you have to unprotect Also the sheet2...and set the sheets log and chance before you unprotect the sheets...

Comment: @Ferdinando, how does it look now?

Comment: i answered with example how to use protect and unprotect sheet...keep me update..

Comment: Could you explain which sheet(s) are you trying to protect, where is the code (in a module?), how are you trying to protect the sheet(s) i.e. what can the user do with it after protection. What's with the ActievSheet in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this snippet code before and after your code

BEFORE:
' sheet1 and sheet2 are protected

```
Dim pwd As String
Dim ws as WorkSheet
pwd = "password"

For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Unprotect Password:=pwd
Next ws
```

'your code

AFTER:

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.protect Password:=pwd
Next ws
```

Hope this helps

EDIT post after you comment

```
Option Explicit 

Sub FilterAndCopy() 

Dim pwd As String   
Dim sht1, sht2 As Worksheet 
Dim rng As Range    

pwd = "password"    

Set sht1 = Worksheets("SHIFT LOG")  
Set sht2 = Worksheets("CHANGE OF NO'S") 

sht2.Unprotect Password:=pwd 'unprotect the sheet   
sht2.UsedRange.ClearContents ' clear contents   

With Intersect(sht1.Columns("B:BP"), sht1.UsedRange)    

    .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False  
    If .Parent.AutoFilterMode Then .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False   

    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Change of Numbers"    

    .Range("A:F, AD:AD, BL:BO").Copy Destination:=sht2.Cells(4, "B")    
    .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False  


    .Range("F:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True   
    .Range("AE:BK").EntireColumn.Hidden = True  

End With    

'Go to last cell in column B    
With ActiveSheet    

    Range("B5").Select  
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select    

End With    

sht2.Protect Password:=pwd ' protect the sheet  


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Ferdinando. I just want to lock the second sheet though. So just `CHANGE OF NO'S`

Comment: OK if you want lock only second sheet you can delete for loop and write only ws.Unprotect Password:=pwd and the end ws.protected Password:=pwd

Comment: Set sh2=worksheets("CHANGE OF NO'S")             sh2.Unprotect Password:=pwd.                               Your code                                                                     sh2.Protect Password:=pwd

Comment: Can you update this in your question with my whole code.

Comment: I'm unsure which part goes where.

Comment: I've provide a visual on this @Ferdinando. Is this right?

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks mate